# Avoid multiple restart of httpd service in bash script

Tags: bash, sh, telegraf

I have a shell script that checks for errors and returns a status '0' (all good) or '1' (needs remediation). I am looking to add a httpd restart command when the check fails (which will ideally fix the issue). However I don't want the service to be restarted too often, say not more that 4 times.

Below is the shell script:

```
response=$(curl -s --max-time 15 --header ‘Host: xyz.testurl.com’ "https://localhost/login/creds.kcc?&TARGET=https:xyz.testurl.com" --insecure 2>/dev/null)

if [ "$response" = "error_msg" ]
then
        echo "Service,host=$prd,pattern=errocheck value=1"
else
        echo "Service,host=$prd,pattern=errocheck value=0"
fi
```

I can append a `service httpd restart` command in the if loop, but that would mean it will restart the service every time error check fails. I would like to keep some kind of control on the restarts.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If your question is

- if "$response" = "error_msg", then execute "service httpd restart"
- but, restarts are not more than 4 times.

So,

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in $(seq 4)
do
    response=$(curl -s --max-time 15 --header ‘Host: xyz.testurl.com’ "https://localhost/login/creds.kcc?&TARGET=https:xyz.testurl.com" --insecure 2>/dev/null)
    if [ "$response" != "error_msg" ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
    service httpd restart
    sleep 10 # temporary solution                                               
done
exit 1
```